# Как записать в JS значение переменной от Label

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Суть моей задачи стоит в том, чтобы по клику кнопки, у меня открывалась ссылка в новой вкладке, я это делаю через `JavaScript`, выглядит это следующим образом:

```
    function bthShowHistory3Click() {
        var pipeyear = document.getElementById("lblYear").value;
        var pipenumber = document.getElementById("lblPipeNo").value;
        url = 'Reports/PipeHistoryReport.aspx?PIPE_NUMBER=' + pipeyear + pipenumber;
        window.open(url, 'GeometryWindow', 'toolbar=0,menubar=1,location=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
        return false;
    }
```

так выглядит разметка лейблов:

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" Style="border-right: gray 1px solid; border-top: gray 1px solid; border-left: gray 1px solid; border-bottom: gray 1px solid; height: 20px; padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 2px; display: inline;">00</asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="lblPipeNo" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" Style="border-right: gray 1px solid; padding-right: 4px; border-top: gray 1px solid; display: inline; padding-left: 4px; border-left: gray 1px solid; border-bottom: gray 1px solid; height: 20px">000000</asp:Label>
```

Но как я понял `.value` не применим к `asp:Label`. дебаггер ругался на подобный код,  как в таком случае достучаться до значений `Label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> дебаггер ругался на подобный код

Какими словами?

```
var pipeyear = document.getElementById("<%= lblYear.ClientID %>").textContent;
```

Comment: что он не может получить значение value если оно null или не определено

Comment: @Sosiska Я так и думал :). Что делaть - в ответе.

Comment: ну я попробовал ваш вариант, и значение переменной `undefined`. хм...

Comment: решил это через `.innerText`

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementById('lblYear').innerHTML)
```